# Posting on facebook page on behalf of another page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

Possible duplicate: [FB Graph API: Posting as a page, to a different page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356247/post-to-facebook-page-wall-as-a-page)

**Problem Statement**:
I was trying to publish a post, say, from ABC page to XYZ page and ended up with this error:

`(#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id other than EVENT or GROUP`

> **Note**: I've an access_token of user's page (in this case: ABC).

**What I've tried so far**:
I'm using [facebook_sdk for python](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-wall-post) to initiate an API calls.

```
# access_token of page on behalf the post will be published
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

response = graph.put_wall_post(
    message=facebook_post_data,
    profile_id=profile_id  # on which post will be published
)
```

which is equivalent to

```
{app-id}/feed?access_token=access_token&message=Hello&method=post
```

> **manage_pages**, **publish_pages**, **publish_actions** are already in the scopes to grant!

**Question**:
Is there no way to solve this issue? or Am I missing something?!?
[Because it's possible to publish post to a page from another page using Facebook UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bFNx.png).

Hence, Graph API documentation doesn't contain any explicit info. about the same, If it's not possible!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: No there is no way to do that